# SMTP, IIS7 and Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis-7, smtp

I'm having trouble setting up SMTP to relay through a 3rd party server.

I'm new to Server 2008 so please bear with me.

I have found the SMTP server in IIS6 which is currently off, but is there one I need to use in IIS7? (IIS7 websites do have the SMTP icon so that 'role' must be installed).

I have used the IIS7 icon to set the remote name and credentials. Using a little test website to send an email to my hotmail account, it comes up saying

Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 ... we do not relay

or occassionally it says 
The remote name could not be resolved: 'The SMTP URL'

I can send using localhost but because that is effectivly spoofing the "from address" loads of them get bounced back!

Anyone got any ideas????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry,  it turns out the people in control of the relay server gave us the wrong username and password, so it would never have worked!

Also, didn't need SMTP server in IIS6 either, so will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Good to hear you got it sorted. For posterity's sake, if you need to run a SMTP service in IIS7, you need to install the IIS6 "bits" which includes the IIS SMTP service.

One fun gotcha--service gets installed as a manual start for some reason, that was fun to troubleshoot at 3am after the 7th tequila shot.